# Range of dates using Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, calendar, frontend

I am using Primefaces on a project and I have two fields for entering dates, " Start Date " and " Date end" need to know how do I get the number of days that are in this range , does anyone have any idea?

I'm using  `<p:calendar>`

Comment: How is this question PrimeFaces related?

Comment: What about `long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);` (Java-8-code)?

Answer (score 0):

[Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) could help you with achieving this

```
DateMidnight start = new DateMidnight("2010-01-01");
DateMidnight end = new DateMidnight("2011-01-07");

int days = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
```